# Car control with Swipe(including No Physics)

Tags: c#, swipe, smoothing

I want to make a code with endless 3d car game, car control by swipe left and right. without using any physics.
info.
3-lane,specific lane center (9,0,car z position),(0,0,car z position),(-9,0,car z position).

I do swipe control and move swipe control but not good.

```
public class playercontrol: MonoBehaviour {

  public void Update() {
    playera.transform.Translate((Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime));
    Debug.Log("speed" + speed);

    if (check == false) {
      if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        Debug.Log("left button");

        firstPressPos = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
      }

      if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {

        secondPressPos = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);

        currentSwipe = new Vector2(secondPressPos.x - firstPressPos.x, secondPressPos.y - firstPressPos.y);

        currentSwipe.Normalize();

        //swipe left
        if (currentSwipe.x < -1.0 f && currentSwipe.y > -0.5 f && currentSwipe.y < 0.5 f) {
          Debug.Log("left swipe");
          if (transform.position.x > -9 f) {
            spos = transform.position;
            Debug.Log("spos" + spos);
            endpos = new Vector3(transform.position.x - 9 f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z + ((speed * 2) / 20));
            Debug.Log("speed......... ......." + ((speed * 5) / 20));
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, -10.0 f, 0);
            check = true;
            //endpos * (Time.deltaTime*0.5f);
            //  Time.timeScale = 0.5f;
            //                          to.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, 0);
          }

        }

        //swipe right
        if (currentSwipe.x > 1.0 f && currentSwipe.y > -0.5 f && currentSwipe.y < 0.5 f) {
          Debug.Log("right swipe");
          if (transform.position.x < 9 f) {
            Debug.Log("spos1" + spos);
            spos = transform.position;
            endpos = new Vector3(transform.position.x + 9 f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z + ((speed * 2) / 20));
            Debug.Log("speed1......... ......." + ((speed * 5) / 20));
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 10.0 f, 0);
            check = true;
            //  Time.timeScale = 0.5f;
            //  to.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, 0);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if (check == true) {
      time += 10 * Time.deltaTime;
      transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(spos, endpos, time);
      //    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp (from.rotation, to.rotation, time);

      if (time > 1) {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
        //Time.timeScale = 1.0f;    
        //playera.transform.Rotate (0, 0, 0);
        //transform.Rotate (0, 0, 0);
        check = false;
        time = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "...not good..." - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: Thanks for replay @JohnB my all code ok but My endless game is not good car  controlling means that you ever play subway suffers or temple run game I need that type of smoothness and control of my car(Only move left and Right specific location with swipe and not use of physics means that in my game I can not use while collider ). Ones again thanks buddy